# Natural Deduction - 'monotone' property of sequent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, natural-deduction

In natural deduction, what says that the following is correct?

$\Gamma \Rightarrow B$ then $  \Gamma, A \Rightarrow B$

I saw a proof that uses this rule without mentioning it and I can't find the rule/axiom/proof for it.

Comment: This is the inference rule called weakening. Depending on the kind of natural deduction system you have, it can be an inference rule or a meta-theorem about your system. Could you give the explicit list of rules you are using? Or at least a reference.

Answer (score 2):

See [Chiswell & Hodges](https://books.google.it/books?id=c4QSDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA61) : Natural Deduction has the Monotonicity property :

> If $Γ ⊆ Δ$ and $Γ \vdash \varphi$, then $Δ \vdash \varphi$.

Suppose $Γ \vdash \varphi$. This means that there is a *derivation* $D$ whose
conclusion is $\varphi$ and whose undischarged assumptions are all in $Γ$.

Given that $Γ ⊆ Δ$, the undischarged assumptions of $D$ are also in
$Δ$, so that $D$ proves $Δ \vdash \varphi$.

Comment: In class we defined $\vdash$ as the yield relation, and we defined $T \vdash_{NDC} A$ meaning there exists a proof for the sequent $ \Gamma => A$ where $\Gamma \subseteq T$. We also defined the property you mentioned for the yield relation but not for sequents from what I checked. Is it possible to infere the rule for sequents from the property of the yield relation?

Comment: @Eloo - may you give us the ref to the textbook used ?

Comment: Similar example in Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic for Computer Science](http://www.win.tue.nl/~keesh/ow/2if85/Ben-Ari3rd.pdf), page 69. In this case $\Rightarrow$ is a *connective* and thus $U \Rightarrow V$ a formula of the language.

Comment: If so, see [Sequent calculus : inference rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules) : Structural rules : Weakening (Left and Right).